# How do I get the list of attributes of an object not returned by dir

Tags: python

`dir(OldStyleClass)` does not return all the attributes of an `OldStyleClass`. In the following example a `dir` instance of an old style class does not return `__class__`:

```
class OldStyleClass:
    pass

old = OldStyleClass()
dir(old)
['__doc__', '__module__']
print  old.__class__
 __main__.OldStyleClass
```

`help(dir)` also says that "some of the attributes" are returned. Is there a way to get the list of attributes of an object that are not displayed by `dir`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to follow the class down; the `__class__` attribute is defined on the type:

```
>>> type(OldStyleClass)
<type 'classobj'>
>>> dir(type(OldStyleClass))
['__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
```